# Is there a word for "active activities?"

Tags: single-word-requests

What can I use as the opposite of "passive activities"? "Active activities" sounds too complicated due to the repetition. For example,

> I enjoy active activities such as sport, dancing or laser tag.

Comment: What's "passive activity"? The only definition I could find is: **`Activity in which the taxpayer did not materially participate in during the tax year.`**.

Comment: @rudra: I would class something like playing a board game as passive

Comment: Because you're making up your own arbitrary distinction between "active" and "passive", this isn't really answerable. Your best bet is to just think about what you want to say and say it.

Comment: @rudra watching television.

Comment: We could also consider a passive activity as an activity in which the person doesn't take part, for example, as a spectator at a football game, or indeed, as a viewer of a football game on television (@cornbread-ninja). Then we could classify a non-passive activity as one in which the person engages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say OP enjoys ***physical*** activities (as opposed to ***sedentary*** pastimes such as chess, bridge, board games, etc.).

Comment: I think the pair *[vigorous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigorous)* and *[sedentary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sedentary)* or the pair *[physical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/physical)* and *[mental](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mental)* are better pairs than *physical* and *sedentary*.

Comment: @jwpat7: OP wants to contrast against "passive" activities. ***Vigorous** activities*, imho, wouldn't include, for example, golf or darts. But I would not call those "passive" activites - they're all primarily "physical" as opposed to sedentary/intellectual pastimes such as reading, playing cards, etc..

Answer (score 3):

*Active pursuits* avoids the repetition, though is still tautological if you consider that *pursuit* means *activity*.

As others have mentioned, *passive* isn’t really the right word to describe something that requires effort (however gentle that effort may be), and *passive activities* is somewhat contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider saying *strenuous* activities if the intention is to indicate exertion.

Answer (score 2):

A passive activity is a bit of an oxymoron, and an active activity is repetition.

I think what you are looking for is 'gentle activity' and 'energetic activity'.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned playing board games as an example of a "passive activity," I'm guessing the words that you're looking for are:

> 1. indoor activities/ games
>
>    - and -
> 2. outdoor activities/ games

Comment: Probably not.  Indoor activities can include swimming, bowling, pushups among other things.  Outdoor activities can include watching football, drinking beer, taking a nap, among other things.